# Is there any free simple SCORM 2004 Javascript player?

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

Is there any free, open source lightweight SCORM 2004 player in Javascript? I am looking something not bound to any technology (PHP, .NET, Java), just implementing basic SCORM 2004 LMS API functions, handling error codes and maybe parsing SCORM manifest. Thanks.

**Update:** I have made a [very very simple JavaSript SCORM 2004 API](http://sites.google.com/site/xmedeko/code/misc/simple-javascript-scorm-2004-api) (But still looking for some more mature code).

**Update2:** I have found a very nice project [TinyLMS](http://www.randelshofer.ch/tinylms/). It's SCORM 1.2 only, but I have negotiated with my client that SCORM 1.2 would be sufficient. So I am gonna make a solution based on TinyLMS.

Comment: How can I use database like MySQL to combine with TinyLMS? It seems that the html exported by TinyLMS can't communicate with mysql.

Comment: @gaussclb Common scenario is to call a server by AJAX and the server uses the DB. On the server side you may use any common programming language, like PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, C#, ...

Comment: Is there a demo? I don't know how to create tables of DB corresponding to cmi.xxx of LMS.

Comment: @gaussclb this question is about pure Javascript SCORM player only. If you need a full integration with a server and DB, check [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) and others.

Comment: I have tried Sakai(Java), but it will create enormous database and is too complicated. I  just want to a lightweight LMS which can interact with database, so is there a tutorial that we can create our own database and interact with LMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slowly growing it - https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot.  This was focused more for the content implementation of SCORM 2004/1.2 Protocols.  There is a Local_API_1484_11.js which is meant as a mimc of the LMS Runtime.  This is light weight and not as robust as a full implementation, but a start at any rate.
I based much the work on Claude Ostyn and countless other resources online (ADL, scorm.com etc ..)

If you are affiliated with a non-profit/non-commercial project get in contact with me.  I have a more complete version of this.

I also have a bookmarklet for checking the status of content running on a LMS located at http://www.cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. My project is finished. I will try your project if I will have to implement SCORM 2004.

Comment: I'll eventually post the JavaScript SCORM Runtime LMS, but I have some further strengthening of all the errors to do.  My hope is I can allow you to just pass it a students CMI/ADL/SSP JSON Object, then run a session and it will fire an event back out that way it can integrate well in any system.  Course all the backend work in whichever language is up everyone.  I've been storing these currently just to files so I can review them and make a viewer later.

Answer (score 2):

Every real-life, functioning (ergo maintained) API will be bound to some sort of server-side tech in some manner... To see an open source example, you could take a look at Moodle's SCORM module, which provides AICC, SCORM 1.2, and (near-complete) SCORM 2004 support.

https://github.com/moodle/moodle

[ADL](http://legacy.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/default.aspx) also had a test suite and sample RTE for 2004. The link on their site is, of course, broken, but you might be able to find it somewhere on the Web.

Comment: Moodle's implementation is too much bound to the PHP and Moodle itself. I am looking for something like http://www.jcasolutions.com/simple-scorm-lms-adapter but open source and for SCORM 2004.

Comment: Thanks for the ADL link, but their sample RTE is Java applet. The broken links can be fixed by changing www.adlnet.gov -> legacy.adlnet.gov

Answer (score 1):

Also SCORMPool has released it's player recently: http://scormpool.com/search/player.aspx It's free but not open source, though.

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248147/254109).

Comment: scormpool is free open source but no documentation available . you can run scorm through it but cant track the scorm api

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it works beautifully:

https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper

Here's the documentation:

https://pipwerks.com/laboratory/scorm/api-wrapper-javascript/

This is all you need - it's free, and it's easy :)

The top hits on Google all point to commercial products that do exactly what this script does for free, except those companies charge many thousands of dollars for it. Don't believe their scare tactics about how difficult it is to create SCORM conformant applications! That's just a sales ploy to frighten you into buying their products.

Comment: The question is about the SCORM player, not the course SCORM API Wrapper. Sorry, if it is unclear.